# Voice guided navigation on Graphopper

Tags: graphhopper

I have been looking at how to implement voice guided navigation on android using OSM data, but there seems to be not enough documentation online.Does any one know what it might take to add voice guided navigation to graphhopper routing on android? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a text to voice engine. I think google offers one for free integrated in Android but there are certainly free alternatives. And then feed it with the appropriate message from the instruction. To find out which instruction comes next you can use the find method:

ghResponse.getInstructionList().find(currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude)

Comment: thanks @Karussell.looking forward to implement this, and definitely give feedback here.